# D3 Topojson Circle with Radius Scaled in Miles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

(assuming existing projection/topojson)

What I'm trying to do is create a circle at a point ([long,lat]) of radius (r) in miles. I know there is a d3.geo function for this, but after some consideration I don't think it will be very compatible with my particular application.

So now I'm looking for using a native svg `circle` solution, where cx and cy are the lat and long, and r is the radius in miles. I know the cx and cy, but I don't know how to make sure the r is say 15 miles. So the main thing is how to make sure the radius is scaled in miles when drawn in pixel space. There must be someway to use the `projection` function to set the appropriate scale for the radius. But I haven't seen this in practice.

Also I should point out that my projection is dynamic, depending on user events the projection (including scale) can change. So I'm not sure if that will have bearing on how circles are scaled within the context of an existing projection, but I thought I would disclose that to be on the safe side.

Comment: A few issues to consider:

1 mile is a variable distance in pixels depending on how where the user is, as you point out.

The projection function is naive to the underlying map's distances in units. You need some way of informing the projection function as to what 1 mile is in your topojson file. One way to do that is to calculate the distance as a proportion of the distance around the earth in arcradians. See here: https://bl.ocks.org/thomasthoren/6a543c4d804f35a240f9

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this block, I've seen it before in my previous research. However it entails a somewhat lengthy distance to pixel function, and he admits his math might not be 100% right. I hoped that by offering a bounty I would be able to see if there were any more refined alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the built-in circle generator [`d3.geoCircle()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoCircle)?

> Returns a new GeoJSON geometry object of type “Polygon” approximating a circle on the surface of a sphere, with the current [center](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#circle_center), [radius](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#circle_radius) and [precision](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#circle_precision). Any *arguments* are passed to the accessors.

The only task left to you is to calculate the radius of the circle in degrees. Because earth is not a perfect sphere this can become quite challenge of its own. But for many applications an approximation will suffice. Taking just the [mean radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Mean_radius) of *3,958 mi* into account, the calculations can be written as:

```
var EARTH_RADIUS = 3959;                         // mean radius in miles
var radiusMi     = 5;                            // radius to be drawn in miles
var radiusDeg    = radiusMi / EARTH_RADIUS * 90; // radius in degrees for circle generator
```

This can then be passed to the circle generator:

```
var circle = d3.geoCircle().radius(radiusDeg);
```

Finally, the circle generator is used to pass its output via data binding to an appropriate path generator taking into account the projection:

```
svg.append("path")
  .datum(circle)
    .attr("d", path);
```

Have a look at this [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/e882a9cc3af83cc537e685ebccca0535) which features circles of 50 miles radius each at various positions around the globe. The circle generator in combination with the projection will take control of the correct sizing and the correct appearance of the circle.

[image]

---

### D3 v3

If you are still stuck to D3 v3 the example works as well. However, you need to adjust the [names](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md) accordingly:

> - d3.geo.circle ↦ [d3.geoCircle](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoCircle)

In addition to that, some of the circle generator's methods have been renamed:

- `circle`.[`origin()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Paths.md#circle_origin) ↦ `circle`.[`center()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#circle_center)
- `circle`.[`angle()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Paths.md#circle_angle) ↦ `circle`.[`radius()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#circle_radius)

Applying those adjustments to my above linked Block, this works for v3 just as well: [v3 Block](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/9f52f26f6fe060b6fadab7688f88842e).

---

This approach gets to play to its strengths when it comes to unusual projections having severe distortions. Just by changing the projection in the Block to [`d3.geoGnomonic()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection#geoGnomonic) this becomes easily visible. The following screenshot from the updated [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/5288be00f422a805a6bc50a621224adb) still shows the same circles as above having a radius of 50 miles each:

[image]

Comment: Great explanation, it helps me make sense of the bigger picture. Let me play around with it and get back to you.

Comment: After more testing, I must stand by my assessment that I alluded to in the first few lines of my post. Using native svg circles would make my life much easier. However your answer here was well explained, so I was optimistic and gave it the benefit of that doubt. I may not be able to use it for my original circle application (need svg) but I still tried in [this](http://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/aac0758110dadd352ed730887d348ec0) minimal block I made to test out your d3.geo. I'm using d3 v3. Not working though. So if dont mind going the extra mile, could you tackle these two issues?

Comment: Leaving aside native svg circles aside for a moment. I will assume that d3.geo.circle can do everything native svg circles can once I understand it more. Don't get me wrong, I'm warming up to this approach, but it's a little challenging because things further up the pipeline are svg circles and my environment expects similar interfacing. For example, I need to be able dynamically change the radius. With native svg: `my_circle.attr({r:my_new_radius_value})` However, when I tried `my_geo_circle.angle(my_new_radius_value)` I got not a function error. Is there a way around this?

Comment: After adding: `my_geo_circle.datum(new_circle).attr(d, geo_path)` I could change the radius dynamically. Bear with my learning curve, I'm not the sharpest tool in the cartographic tool shed. Anyway, your solution ended up working out quite well, thank you so much. I hereby award you 50 bounty!

Comment: Is `radiusMi / EARTH_RADIUS * 90` wrong? I think you need `radiusMi / EARTH_RADIUS * 360 / (2 * Math.PI)`.